# Axis ClassCast exception

Tags: java, liferay

I am facing a strange problem with axis in liferay. Whenever my portlet is deployed I get the following error in CONSOLE :

```
1org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanSerializerFactory cannot be cast to org.apache.axis.encoding.SerializerFactory
```

Althought this doesn't affect my functionality, the portlet works, but I need to remove this exception

Any helps, please :(

Answer (score 0):

Please check your classpath - do you have two conflicting versions of axis on the path? Check the application that's deployed, not the one in your development environment.

Comment: When I find AxisServlet by Ctrl+Shift+T, I found that there are two AxisServlet come from util-java.jar and axis.jar, is that the problem?

Comment: One more thing, in buildPath of my portlet project, I found only one axis.jar on Liferay Portlet Plugin API